# Loop in const object

Tags: javascript, loops, object, constants

I am trying to do the following:

```
const obj {
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
       Key[i]: data[i].description
    }
}
```

(I know I probably also needs to add a comma at the end of each line except on the last one, but I already get errors in the earlier stage)

This doesn't seem to be allowed in JS. Are there any alternatives? Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a const obj = {key0: 'value0',key1: 'value1',key2: 'value2',..} object with the key and value dynamically generated from a JSON-object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) in combination with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and map the single objects with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for the object.

```
const obj = Object.assign(...data.map((o, i) => ({ ['Key' + i]: o.description })));
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to create an object from a keys array and a data array.

A clean approach would be to use array reduction:

```
const obj = data.reduce((obj, d, i) => {
  obj[Key[i]] = d.description;
  return obj;
}, {});
```

which, assuming your environment allows it, can be simplified further (due note that this will be cleaner code but less efficient because the [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals) copies the entire object every time):

```
const obj = data.reduce((obj, d, i) => ({
  ...obj,
  [Key[i]]: d.description
}), {});
```

but you could also use a simple `for` loop:

```
const obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  obj[Key[i]] = data[i].description;
}
```

Note: The code above will break if `Key.length !== data.length`.

Comment: Very nice! Didn't selected this as the best answer because the other one matched my intention better (which also dynamically adds the keys instead of getting those from another array) but my initial question wasn't that clear and this also is a very useful approach. Thank you!! :)